# Remove from a matrix columns by their name in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dgeMatrix and I would like to remove all columns which start with WO using a function grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
m
      WO1 WO2 WO3 C1 C2
 [1,]  59  53  57 57 55
 [2,]  55  51  57 54 51
 [3,]  60  53  57 55 54
 [4,]  59  53  59 50 53
 [5,]  50  60  53 59 60
 [6,]  59  52  54 54 51
 [7,]  57  51  50 57 51
 [8,]  55  58  60 58 55
 [9,]  55  52  57 50 59
[10,]  52  51  59 54 51
m <- m[,-grep('WO',colnames(m))]
m
      C1 C2
 [1,] 57 55
 [2,] 54 51
 [3,] 55 54
 [4,] 50 53
 [5,] 59 60
 [6,] 54 51
 [7,] 57 51
 [8,] 58 55
 [9,] 50 59
[10,] 54 51
```